# Assign new value to DataSeries Row based on conditional statement on pre-existing value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

For a Dataframe, how do I conduct a conditional statement to assign a new value based on preexisting value in a column?

- If the value of Column contains a string of len(>0); then assign a value = 0
- If value of Column is None (NoneType) then assign 1

I am trying to get a counter to check how many of the rows are missing value based on a string length.

I can covert the series to a list and do the test, but I would like to learn how this is possible within the dataframe itself.

```
Dataframe.Series

df['old']   df['old'] (after)

String A       0
String B       0
String C       0
None           1
String D       0
String E       0
None           1

#So that I can sum the df['old'](after) to get counter value 
Sum            2
```

Answer (score 0):

are you just trying to see how many None you have?

you could just do this

```
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame(['a', 'b', None, 'q'], columns=['old'])
df['old'].isnull().sum()

Out[37]: 
1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert the strings to 1 values and the None to 0, you can apply a lambda function:

```
import pandas as pd
x = pd.DataFrame(['S', 'X', 'Z', None, 'B'])

x[0] = x[0].apply(lambda x: 1 if x else 0)
```

Then, to count the values which are one, you could use sum:

```
x[0].sum()
```

Answer (score 0):

For a fast vectorized solution, just use the `isnull` method and multiply by 1 to convert to an integer.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col' :['a','b',None, None, 'sdaf']})
df['count'] = df.col.isnull() * 1
```

output:

```
    col  count
0     a      0
1     b      0
2  None      1
3  None      1
4  sdaf      0
```